# Ruby on Rails - Get array of values from array of hash with particular order of existing keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-1.8.7

The original array likes this:

```
[{:age=>28, :name=>"John", :id=>1}, {:name=>"David", :age=>20, :id=>2, :sex=>"male"}]
```

Order of existing keys:

```
[:id, :name, :age] or ['id', 'name', 'age']
```

The result should be:

```
[[1, "John", 28], [2, "David", 20]]
```

Thank for teaching me.

P/s: I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5

Thanks

Comment: [Ruby 1.8.7 is dead](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/). You shouldn't be using it for new code.

Comment: unfortunately, the project using it. I have no option to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map all the records and then map the attributes in the order given to return the attributes' values in the specified order.

```
records = [
  {:age=>28, :name=>"John", :id=>1},
  {:name=>"David", :age=>20, :id=>2, :sex=>"male"}
]

attributes = [:id, :name, :age]
records.map do |record|
  attributes.map { |attr| record[attr] }
end
```

Comment: We have a direct method --- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-values_at  :)  and in 1.8.7 too http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-values_at

Answer (score 4):

Here is a nice way using [`#values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) :

```
records = [
  {:age=>28, :name=>"John", :id=>1},
  {:name=>"David", :age=>20, :id=>2, :sex=>"male"}
]

attributes = [:id, :name, :age]

records.collect { |h| h.values_at(*attributes) }
# => [[1, "John", 28], [2, "David", 20]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Just curiosity, what best performance in Arup and Ryan answer?

Comment: Nice :) I always forget about little convenience helpers like that. I think @Arup's answer is probably more performant as it does the iterating in C (as that's how `values_at` is defined). My answer does it in Ruby. Probably a tiny tiny difference.

Comment: @RyanBigg You wrote the book? R4IA... WooW!

Comment: Yes that's me :) I had a lot of help from Steve Klabnik and Rebecca Skinner on this new edition.

Comment: @RyanBigg Any chance to help this [issue](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/6032) ?

Comment: @RyanBigg I have same problem like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469348/ruby-how-to-retrieve-sum-in-array-group-by-multiple-keys-with-condition-max/ Could you take a look?

Comment: @Anh If you have a problem.. why did you accept? You can ask people who already tried to help you.

Comment: @RyanBigg I accept before I realize the other problem in Mr Cary's answer. He will answer later. As urgent case, so I bother you. Sorry, if you are busy now.