# Ruby - How to retrieve sum in array group by multiple keys with condition max

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

The original array is

```
[
    {"id"=>2, "idx"=>111, "money"=>"4.00", "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1"},
    {"id"=>1, "idx"=>112, "money"=>"2.00", "money1"=>"2.00", "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1"},
    {"id"=>3, "idx"=>113, "money"=>"3.00", "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"002", "order1"=>"2"}
]
```

The expected array should:

```
[
    {"id"=>2, "idx"=>112, "money"=>"6.00", "money1"=>"3.00","order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1"},
    {"id"=>3, "idx"=>113, "money"=>"3.00", "money1"=>"1.00","order"=>"002", "order1"=>"2"}
]
```

The call likes `f_addition(arr, group_fields, sum_fields, max_fields)` (e.x: `f_addition(arr, ["order","order1"], ["money","money1"], ["id", "idx"]` )

P/s: the original should not be changed after calling method (it is used again as parameter for new group_fields, new sum_fields, new max_fields)

Similar problem in topic [Hash of Arrays, group by and sum by with many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392563/ruby-on-rails-hash-of-arrays-group-by-and-sum-by-with-many-columns)

Comment: Compact and unambiguous statement of an interesting problem that I expect has useful application.

Comment: waiting your answer. I want get total, and get max for ordering later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

**Code**

```
def f_addition(arr, group_fields, sum_fields, max_fields)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |h,g|
    g.update( h.values_at(*group_fields) => h ) do |_,gv,hv|
      gv.merge(hv) do |k,gvv,hvv|
        case
        when sum_fields.include?(k) then "%.2f" % (gvv.to_f + hvv.to_f)
        when max_fields.include?(k) then [gvv, hvv].max
        else gvv
        end
      end
    end
  end.values
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [{ "id"=>2, "idx"=>111, "money"=>"4.00", "money1"=>"1.00",
         "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "pet"=>"dog" },
       { "id"=>1, "idx"=>112, "money"=>"2.00", "money1"=>"2.00",
         "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "sport"=>"darts" },
       { "id"=>3, "idx"=>113, "money"=>"3.00", "money1"=>"1.00",
         "order"=>"002", "order1"=>"2" }]
```

Notice that the this array is slightly different from from the one given in the question. I have added `"pet"=>"dog"` to the first (hash) element `"sport"=>"darts"`and to the second hash.

```
f_addition(arr, ["order","order1"], ["money","money1"], ["id", "idx"] )
  #=> [{ "id"=>2, "idx"=>112, "money"=>"6.00", "money1"=>"3.00",
  #      "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "pet"=>"dog", "sport"=>"darts"},
  #    { "id"=>3, "idx"=>113, "money"=>"3.00", "money1"=>"1.00",
  #      "order"=>"002", "order1"=>"2" }]
```

**Explanation**

For the example above:

```
group_fields = ["order", "order1"]
sum_fields   = ["money", "money1"]
max_fields   = ["id", "idx"]

enum = arr.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{"id"=>2, "idx"=>111,..., "pet"=>"dog"},
  #     {"id"=>1, "idx"=>112,..., "sport"=>"darts"},
  #     {"id"=>3,"idx"=>113,...,"order1"=>"2"}]:each_with_object({})>
```

[Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) passes each element of this enumerator into the block and assigns it to the block variables. The first element passed is:

```
h, g = enum.next
  #=> [{ "id"=>2, "idx"=>111, "money"=>"4.00", "money1"=>"1.00",
         "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "pet"=>"dog" }, {}]  
h #=>  { "id"=>2, "idx"=>111, "money"=>"4.00", "money1"=>"1.00",
         "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "pet"=>"dog" } 
g #=>  {}
```

As:

```
h.values_at(*group_fields)
  #=> h.values_at(*["order", "order1"])
  #=> h.values_at("order", "order1")
  #=> ["001", "1"]
```

we compute:

```
g.update(["001", "1"] => h) do |k,gv,hv| ... end
```

which is shorthand for:

```
g.update({ ["001", "1"] => h }) do |k,gv,hv| ... end
```

The block `do |k,gv,hv| ... end` is only used when the two hashes being merged both contain the key `k`.<sup>1</sup> As `g = {}` contains no keys, the block is not used at this time:

```
g.update({ ["001", "1"] => h })
  #=> {}.update({ ["001", "1"]=>{ "id"=>2, "idx"=>111, "money"=>"4.00",
  #                               "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"001",
  #                               "order1"=>"1", "pet"=>"dog" } }
  #=> { ["001", "1"]=>{ "id"=>2, "idx"=>111, "money"=>"4.00", "money1"=>"1.00",
  #                     "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "pet"=>"dog" } }
```

where the value returned by `update` is the new value of `g`.

The next value of `enum` passed into the block is:

```
h, g = enum.next
h #=> { "id"=>1, "idx"=>112, "money"=>"2.00", "money1"=>"2.00",
  #     "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "sport"=>"darts" },
g #=> { ["001", "1"]=>{ "id"=>2, "idx"=>111, "money"=>"4.00", "money1"=>"1.00",
  #      "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "pet"=>"dog" } }]
```

As:

```
h.values_at(*group_fields)
  #=> h.values_at("order", "order1")
  #=> ["001", "1"]
```

we compute:

```
g.update(["001", "1"] => h) do |k,gv,hv| ... end
```

As `g` and `{ ["001", "1"] => h }` both contain the key ["001", "1"], we must defer to the block to determine the value of that key in the merged hash. We have:

```
k  = ["001", "1"]
gv = { "id"=>2, "idx"=>111, "money"=>"4.00", "money1"=>"1.00",
       "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "pet"=>"dog" }
hv = { "id"=>1, "idx"=>112, "money"=>"2.00", "money1"=>"2.00",
       "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "sport"=>"darts" }
```

We therefore evaluate the block as follows (using `merge` rather than `merge!/update`):

```
gv.merge(hv) do |k,gvv,hvv|
  case
  when sum_fields.include?(k) then "%.2f" % (gvv.to_f + hvv.to_f)
  when max_fields.include?(k) then [gvv, hvv].max
  else gvv
  end
end
  #=> { "id"=>2, "idx"=>112, "money"=>"6.00", "money1"=>"3.00",
  #     "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "pet"=>"dog", "sport"=>"darts"}
```

`gv` does not contain the key "sport", so the block is not used when merging `"sport"=>"darts"` into `gv`. All other keys of `hvv` are present in `gvv`, however, so we use the block to determine their values in the merged hash. For:

```
k = "money"
gvv = "4.00"
hvv = "2.00"
```

we find:

```
sum_fields.include?(k)
  #=> ["money", "money1"].include?("money")
  #=> true
```

so the `case` statement returns:

```
"%.2f" % (gvv.to_f + hvv.to_f)
  #=> "%.2f" % ("4.00".to_f + "2.00".to_f)
  #=> "6.00"
```

The values for other keys of `hv`, the hash being merged into `gv`, are computed similarly, to give us a new value for the merged hash `g`.

Lastly,

```
{ ["002", "order1"] => { "id"=>3, "idx"=>113, "money"=>"3.00",
                         "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"002", "order1"=>"2" }]
```

is merged into `g` (which does not require the use `update`'s block) and `g.values` is returned by the method.

**Observation**

It would be easy to generalize this to pass pairs such as:

```
[["money","money1"], ->(a,b) { "%.2f" % (a.to_f + b.to_f) }]
[["id", "idx"], :max]
```

This could be done as follows:

```
def f_addition(arr, group_fields, *mods)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |h,g|
    g.update( h.values_at(*group_fields) => h ) do |_,gv,hv|
      gv.merge(hv) do |k,gvv,hvv|
        f,op = mods.find { |f,op| f.include?(k) }
        if f
          case op
          when Proc   then op.call(gvv,hvv)
          when Symbol then [gvv, hvv].send(op)
          end
        else
          gvv
        end
      end
    end
  end.values
end

f_addition(arr, ["order","order1"],
                [["money","money1"], ->(a,b) { "%.2f" % (a.to_f + b.to_f) }],
                [["id", "idx"], :max])
  # => [{ "id"=>2, "idx"=>112, "money"=>"6.00", "money1"=>"3.00",
  #       "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1", "pet"=>"dog", "sport"=>"darts" },
  #      { "id"=>3, "idx"=>113, "money"=>"3.00", "money1"=>"1.00",
  #        "order"=>"002", "order1"=>"2" }]
```

```
1. We will find that the calculations in the block do not depend on the block variable `k`.
   I've therefore replaced that variable with the local variable _, to so-inform the reader.
```

Comment: Mr Cary, Great answer! Hope get your explanation. And please do more favor, give your approach step by step (roadmap of your mind) to solve problem like this. Its useful for me -a beginner- to solve myself when getting familiar problems. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty close of what you asked

```
def f_addition(arr, group_fields, sum_fields, max_fields)
  arr.group_by do |h|
    group_fields.map {|k| h[k]}
  end.values.map do |group|
    sums = group.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |h, acc|
      sum_fields.each {|sum_f| acc[sum_f] += h[sum_f].to_f }
    end
    group.first.merge(sums)
  end.flatten
end

arr = [
    {"id"=>2, "idx"=>111, "money"=>"4.00", "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1"},
    {"id"=>1, "idx"=>112, "money"=>"2.00", "money1"=>"2.00", "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1"},
    {"id"=>3, "idx"=>113, "money"=>"3.00", "money1"=>"1.00", "order"=>"002", "order1"=>"2"}
]


f_addition(arr, ["order","order1"], ["money","money1"], ["id", "idx"] )

# [
#   {"id"=>2, "idx"=>111, "money"=>6.0, "money1"=>3.0, "order"=>"001", "order1"=>"1"}
#   {"id"=>3, "idx"=>113, "money"=>3.0, "money1"=>1.0, "order"=>"002", "order1"=>"2"}
# ]
```

Comment: Ismael, "idx" of 1st element of result is "idx"=>112. Max values used for ordering later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
def aggregate(arr, group_fields, sum_fields, max_fields)
arr.group_by { |x| x.values_at(*group_fields) }.map {|key, hashes|
  result = hashes[0].clone
  max_fields.each { |k|
      hashes.map! {|h| h.merge(h) { |k, v| Integer(v) rescue v }}
      #hashes.map! { |h| h.each_pair { | k, v | h[k] = Integer(v) rescue v }}
      result[k] = hashes.max_by { |h| h[k]}[k]
  }

  sum_fields.each { |k|
    result[k] = hashes.inject(0) { |s, x| s + x[k].to_f }
  }
  result
}end
```

One thing not good is that to convert all fields to int (convert to int for comparison in case: `"id"=>"12"` and `"id"=>"2"`). Should convert max_fields only, but I dont think a solution yet. Code for convert is:

`hashes.map! {|h| h.merge(h) { |k, v| Integer(v) rescue v }}`
Or

`hashes.map! { |h| h.each_pair { | k, v | h[k] = Integer(v) rescue v`

So, its great if someone could solve this weak point.

Comment: Regarding the conversions between strings and numbers, that is indeed a messy (but not difficult) aspect of the problem.  I concluded that it was easiest to convert strings to numbers as needed, then convert back to strings.  It might be clearest to convert certain fields from strings to numbers as a separate initial step, then convert back to strings at the end.  btw, shouldn't the conversions be to floats?  I ran your code with the example in my answer. I noticed that the key-value pair `"sport"=>"darts"` did not get merged. (cont.)

Comment: There are of course many ways to do an initial conversion of the values of the `sum` keys.  One is `arr.map { |h| h.merge(h) { |k,v,_| sum_fields.include?(k) ? v.to_f : v } }`.